# Error in View code (need an "end"?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is the error I'm getting. I got the impression from this error trace that there was an unmatched "end", but I don't know what type to insert. None of the earlier multi-line clauses are unclosed, as far as I can detect. Appreciate your assistance and I hope that I can repay the favor. Note that I would not be including all this irrelevant and unneeded text if the StackOverflow bot were not complaining about my high code:text ratio.

```
SyntaxError in Users#new
Showing /home/max/Desktop/coding/auth_ex/app/views/users/new.html.erb where line #52 raised:

/home/max/Desktop/coding/auth_ex/app/views/users/new.html.erb:52: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting keyword_end
/home/max/Desktop/coding/auth_ex/app/views/users/new.html.erb:54: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
Extracted source (around line #52):
49
50
51


   <hr>
    -->

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/users/new.html.erb

Rails.root: /home/max/Desktop/coding/auth_ex

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
Request

Parameters:

None
Toggle session dump
Toggle env dump
Response

Headers:

None
```

So here's the code in the view that I'm accessing.

---

```
<!-- Sign up Users -->

    <div class="itembox">
        <p class="bigfont"> Sign up user </p>
            <%= form_for @user do |f| %>
                <% if @user.errors.any? %>
                    <div class="error_messages">
                        <p class="bigfont"> Form is invalid </p>
                            <ul>
                                <% for message in @user.errors.full_messages %>
                                    <li><%= message %></li>
                                <% end %>
                            </ul>
                    </div>
                <% end %>
                <p> <%= f.label :email %>   <%= f.text_field :email %> </p>
                <p> <%= f.label :password %> <%= f.password_field :password %> </p>
                <p> <%= f.label :password_confirmation %> <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %> </p>
                <p class="button"><%= f.submit %></p>
            <% end %>
    </div>

<hr>

<!-- Sign In a user -->

    <div class="itembox">
        <p class="bigfont">Sign IN a user</p>
        <p> <%= form_for @session do |s| %></p>
        <p><%= f.label :name %></p>
        <p><%= f.label :password %></p>
        l<p class="button"> <%= f.submit %></p>
    </div>

<hr>

<!-- Users List -->
    <div class="itembox">
        <p class="bigfont"> Users List </p>
        <% @users.each do |u| %>
            <%= u.id %>)
            <%= u.email %>
            <br><br>
        <% end %>
    </div>

<hr>
```

I'm really not sure what the problem is because I can't find any "end" that I'm missing. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

end for this block is missing

<%= form_for @session do |s| %>

<%= f.label :name %>

<%= f.label :password %>

one more thing you are accessing f.label etc in that while the scope of f is already end now you have to do that with s.label

Answer (score 1):

Im not find `end` after this form i think problem here

```
<div class="itembox">
    <p class="bigfont">Sign IN a user</p>
    <p> <%= form_for @session do |s| %></p>
    <p><%= f.label :name %></p>
    <p><%= f.label :password %></p>
    l<p class="button"> <%= f.submit %></p>
</div>
```

Observe the indentation